# RxSwift TableView with swipe actions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I'm using `RxSwift` with `RxDataSources` framework to setup a tableview:

```
let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<AnimatableSectionModel<String, String>>(configureCell: { _, tableView, indexPath, item -> UITableViewCell in
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellwithIdentifier: "TestCell", for: indexPath)
       cell.configure()
       return cell
})

vm.cellViewModels
     .map({ [AnimatableSectionModel(model: "", items: $0)] })
     .bind(to: _view.tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
     .disposed(by: bag)
```

I'm trying to get my `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` to work in `UITableViewDelegate`, and setting the delegate as:

`tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: bag)`

At the same time setting the delegate methods as:

```
extension UIViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { action, view, completion in
            
        }

        action.image = Images.shared.logo.resized(to: CGSize(width: 24, height: 24)).tintWithColor(.darkGray).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        action.backgroundColor = .clear

        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
        configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false

        return configuration
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 20))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return headerView
    }
}
```

The header is called and works as expected, meaning the delegate should be set correct.

---

Doing it without RxSwift, works for swipe actions.

Does anyone know how to get `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` to work with RxDatasources, as I can only get `viewForHeaderInSection` to work?

Comment: I found the issue. Adding this method, fixed the swipe actions:

`dataSource.canEditRowAtIndexPath = { datasource, index -> Bool in return true }`